# Extract pattern from several hundreds files

Tags: string, awk, design-patterns

I have several hundreds of `*.changelog` files named generated by `rpm -q --changelog` named `package01.changelog`, `package02.changelog`, `package03.changelog`, and so on...

I want to extract the CVE (Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures) numbers from each of them and create two separate files:

1. One file that lists all CVEs for *each* `*.changelog` file, for example:

```
CVE-2014-3513 | CVE-2014-3567 | CVE-2014-3568
```

2. A second file that concatenates all CVE's from *all* `*.changelog` files, for example:

```
CVE-2014-3513:package01 | CVE-2014-3567:package02 | CVE-2014-3568:package03
```

The CVEs listed in the the `*.changelog` files are not placed in a specific order or have a specific structure, for example:

```
  references (add CVE-2022-28356 bsc#1197391).
  (CVE-2022-1016 bsc#1197227).
  in error path (CVE-2022-28389 bsc#1198033).
- xprtrdma: fix incorrect header size calculations (CVE-2022-0812
  bsc#1196761 CVE-2022-0850).


(add CVE-2022-28356 bsc#1197391)
(CVE-2022-1016 bsc#1197227).
(CVE-2022-0812
CVE-2022-0850).
  (bsc#1196836 CVE-2022-26966).
```

I am using a loop to go through *each* `*.changelog` file, extract the CVEs and write them to the two output files mentioned above, for example:

```
for chlg in /path/to/*.changelog
do
  pkg_name="$(echo $(basename $chlg) | sed 's/.changelog//')"
  cve_file="$(echo $(basename $chlg) | sed 's/.changelog/.cve.html/')"
 
  grep -o 'CVE-[[:digit:]]*-[[:digit:]]*' $chlg | sort -f | uniq | awk -v pkg_name="$pkg_name" -v cve_file="/path/to/${cve_file}" -v all_cve_file="/path/to/cve.html" '
        {
          print "<a href=\"https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name="$1"\" target=\"_blank\" title=\""$1"\">"$1"</a> | " > cve_file
          print "<a href=\"https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name="$1"\" target=\"_blank\" title=\""$1"\">"$1"</a>:<span style=\"color:red; font-family:consolas;\">"pkg_name"</span> | " >> all_cve_file
        }'
done
```

I get what the results I want, even though it's taking more than an hour to finish considering that I'm processing ~ 49000 files. Another issue (that's a discussion for a different topic) is that the resulting `cve.html` file is too big to be loaded by a browser which eventually crashes.

My question is if the approach I'm using to extract the CVE numbers from these ~49000 files is good enough or if there is another more "elegant" and efficient way.

Comment: `sort` has a `-u` option so you can avoid using `uniq` . But otherwise seems reasonable. If you really need it to be faster look at using `gnu-parallel` or `xargs` but you'll spend a some time getting it to work. Is is really worth the trouble? Good luck.

Comment: AND as you seem to have code that is working, this is really more appropriate to [codereview.se].  Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) ,   [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  ,  [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [mcve] before posting more Qs here. Good Luck

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion about `sort -u`. I knew `sort` had that option, but for some reason, I've been always using `uniq`. In any case, I removed `uniq` from my script and replaced with `sort -u`. One less pipe...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion regarding [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) as well. I didn't know it existed. I will be using it from now on for code that is already working.

Comment: Before posting on Code Review please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

You might implement getting unique values in GNU `AWK` itself and then `sort -f` them which might shorten time if number of CVEs total is much greater that number of unique CVEs, this can be done following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
  references (add CVE-2022-28356 bsc#1197391).
  (CVE-2022-1016 bsc#1197227).
  in error path (CVE-2022-28389 bsc#1198033).
- xprtrdma: fix incorrect header size calculations (CVE-2022-0812
  bsc#1196761 CVE-2022-0850).


(add CVE-2022-28356 bsc#1197391)
(CVE-2022-1016 bsc#1197227).
(CVE-2022-0812
CVE-2022-0850).
  (bsc#1196836 CVE-2022-26966).
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="CVE-[[:digit:]]*-[[:digit:]]*"}$1&&!arr[$1]++{print $1}' file.txt | sort -f
```

gives output

```
CVE-2022-0812
CVE-2022-0850
CVE-2022-1016
CVE-2022-26966
CVE-2022-28356
CVE-2022-28389
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field is `CVE-` followed by zero-or-more (`*`) digits followed by `-` followed by zero-or-more digits. Then I `print` 1st field if there is 1st field and it was not seen earlier which fact is stored in array `arr`.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion to use this option of `awk`. It is certainly  cleaner even though it didn't shorten the time of processing.

Comment: As I have to direct the output to different files, like in my example above, how would I do it  in one pass with the option you provided? Using multiple `print` statements?